# reset state in VUEX after triggered function in mutations (VueJS)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, default, reset

I want to `reset` all values inside of my `state` to `default` when a method in `mutations` is triggered, which means all `state values` should not be filled anymore.

Normally I will fill my variables with some values from my vue components, but when `reset_data` is triggered i want to  `reset` all to default.

How can I achieve this in VueX? Thank You!

***STORE.TS:***

```
export default createStore({
    state: {
        test1: "",
        test2: "",
        test3: "",
        test4: "",
        test5: "",
    },

    mutations: {
        reset_state(state) {
          //this function will be triggered from a component in my VueJS project
          //here I want to reset my state
        }
    }
})
```

**INFO: I don't search for a solution to just declared every variable (test1, test2, ...) for it's own.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. Copy the object:

```
let data = {
     test1: "",
     test2: "",
     test3: "",
     test4: "",
     test5: "",
}

export default createStore({
    state: { ...data },

    mutations: {
        reset_state(state) {
          state = { ...data }
        }
    }
})
```

You need to spread it to lose its reference.